# Return specified field using findById | Mongoose MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When using the Model.findOne() method, I can choose to include a string that limits my return value to just those field, but when I try to do so with the findById method, it appears to not work out.

The example below is a contrived example. I'm using a real _id and it works when using the first example, but I just want to use the findById method because a tiny voice in the back of my mind is telling me that's faster (maybe).

Example:

```
let Joe = new PersonModel({
  _id: ObjectId("12345")
  name: 'Joe',
  age: 30,
  password: 'GreatPW'
}).save();
```

Now find Joe, and return only his name and age. This works!

```
PersonModel.findOne({_id: Joe._id}, 'name age')
  .then(person => console.log(person))
```

Now do the same thing, but using findById(). This isn't working for me.

```
PersonModel.findById(Joe._id, 'name age')
  .then(person => console.log(person))
```

Comment: findById calls findOne, so it can't be faster. The source is [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById). Projection should work for findById too.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, and this is working now. It must have been something else affecting the code last night. If you add this as an answer, I will mark you as having the correct answer.

Comment: Good to hear it's working. Non-reproducible problems are not really supposed to be answered, so I think my comment is enough. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on logging in Mongoose. you'll see that the only difference between those two calls is an extra function call from **findById** to **findOne**.

Source code reference: [findById](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) (provided by MikaS)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but I think you need to write {}, on query and in the projection:

This:

```
PersonModel.findById(Joe._id, 'name age')
```

Should be this:

```
PersonModel.findById({idValueToFind}, {name:1, age:1, _id:0})
```